# Google Analytics Cross-Domain: Bad or expired linker parameter hash

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, autolink, analytics.js

I'm implementing cross-domain tracking using autoLinker for a client's Google Analytics tracker on our product. We have a testing site that mimics the client's use case. It seems like our use case is pretty straightforward, but we're getting an error message that reads:

Bad or expired linker parameter hash: 1.131376970.470764749.1481314121
log @ www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Auto cookieDomain found: ""

We've got a pretty simple linker implementation set up. I'm not sure what could be causing this error.

on the client's site:

```
ga('create', [tracker_id], 'auto');

//Autolinker plugin for cross-domain widget tracking
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['<our domain>']);

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

on our site:

```
var opts = {};

if (client_id && <%= ga_crossdomain_enabled? %>) {
  opts['clientId'] = client_id;
}

opts['allowLinker'] = true;

ga('create', '<%= client_tracker_params.tracking_id %>', 'auto', '<%= client_tracker_params.name %>', opts);
```

Comment: Is there a sample page that you can link to? Please add the link to the question and I can try and debug the issue..

Answer (score 0):

try adding allowLinker true on the client's site and make sure both domains added in referral exclusion list, and _ga parameter should append to the clients website URL when you visit the clients website through your website.